# Button inside text box

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

My code shows a button inside a text box; but when the input value changes, the size of the text box also changes.  That I don't like.  Is there any solution such that the textbox size remains fixed?  Or any other idea on how to create a button inside textbox? The following is code from the article [*Component Border*](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/09/27/component-border/):

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout( new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0) );
panel.add(textField);
panel.add(button);
panel.setBackground( textField.getBackground() );
panel.setBorder( textField.getBorder() );
textField.setBorder(null);
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish.  Are you just trying to have a button with text next to it?

Comment: No I have button inside textfeild but have above problem

Answer (score 2):

Your example appears to be the second alternative discussed in the article [*Component Border*](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/09/27/component-border/). Instead, you may want to `install()` a [`ComponentBorder`](http://www.camick.com/java/source/ComponentBorder.java), a third alterative described later in the same article.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any solution such that the textbox size remains fixed?

I'm guessing you are creating the JTextField like:

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField();
```

In this case the text field size changes as you add text to it.

Instead you should use:

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
```

and the text field will remain a constant size an hold a minimum of 10 characters before scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

Try a BorderLayout and add the textfield at BorderLayout.CENTER and the button at BorderLayout.EAST.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code, and it seemed to work fine for me, with a slight modification.  It may be that panel is resizing itself, not textField.  Try wrapping panel in another JPanel to force its shape.

```
JPanel panel      = new JPanel();
JPanel outerPanel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout( new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0) );
panel.add(textField);
panel.add(button);
panel.setBackground( textField.getBackground() );
panel.setBorder( textField.getBorder() );
textField.setBorder(null);
outerPanel.add(panel);
```

Comment: Glad to help.  Good luck on your project.

Answer (score -1):

Use a different Layout, or try absolute positioning

Comment: Absolute positioning is rarely, if ever, a valid solution.  If you have the algorithm to determine the exact location and bounds of a component, it is more logical to create a custom layout of that algorithm.